# Not able to Create regular expression for a Voucher number generated in this format "484,0116/BRD/0000267" and I have to use only 0116/BRD/0000267

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have tried many combinations to extract 0116/BRD/0000267 from this number "484,0116/KMO/0000267" but not able to extract, it is showing ERROR - jmeter.extractor.RegexExtractor: Error in pattern: `[^,](*[0-9]|/|*[A-Z]|/|*[0-9]+?)`"

Please help if anybody have answer for this situation.
Thanks in advance. Images
[Response from web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmBwL.png)
[setting of regular expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRt78.png)

Comment: You cannot apply a `*` quantifier to a `|`.

Comment: I am using template $0$, match number 0. I have removed | and used this value ^(*[0-9]/*[A-Z]/*[0-9]+?)"$ but still showing errors.

Comment: Use [`[^,]*,([0-9]*/[A-Z]*/[0-9]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/lX0qZ5/1) and try with `$1$`. If the substring you need is always at the end add a `$` at the end: [`[^,]*,([0-9]*/[A-Z]*/[0-9]+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/lX0qZ5/2). Well, I think you can even try `[0-9]*/[A-Z]*/[0-9]+`/`[0-9]*/[A-Z]*/[0-9]+$` with your `$0$`

Comment: This time it is not showing error in the expression [0-9]*/[A-Z]*/[0-9]+/[0-9]*/[A-Z]*/[0-9]+$ but showing VoucherNo":"NOT FOUND". Value is still not found as it is my default message when no value found.Thanks your expression was correct but value still missing.

Comment: :) You copied too much, there is a slash diving two alternative patterns :) Use the expression from my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After very long try I have got the answer. Thank you guys for your support. The expression to extract 0116/BRD/0000267 from "484,0116/BRD/0000267" is ,(.+)?\"
This worked for me in Jmeter. Thank you all of you for supporting me., = was bcas I want string after this (.+) = Was for the whole string and numbers ?= was to stop when I got result \" = was to stop before " (inverted comma)
I have used template $1$ and field check in = Body. Image is here for my regex setting. [Regex expression setting for jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFbsa.png)
Thank you :)

We have shared this details on 
http://www.knowledgeworldforyou.com/?p=276

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with this regex is that you inserted pipes (alternation operator in regex) where you really did not intend to use alternation, but continuation. The `*` quantifier cannot be applied to the alternation operator.

Use

```
[0-9]*/[A-Z]*/[0-9]+
```

or (if the substring is always at the end of the string):

```
[0-9]*/[A-Z]*/[0-9]+$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eR9tS3/1)

*Explanation:*

- `[0-9]*` - matches 0 or more digits (perhaps, `*` can be replaced with `+` to match 1 or more occurrences)
- `/` -  a literal forward slash
- `[A-Z]*` - 0 or more uppercase ASCII letters (again, perhaps, `*` can be replaced with `+` to match 1 or more occurrences)
- `/` -  a literal forward slash
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits.

The `$` asserts the position at the end of the string.

**That should work with `$0$` variable.** You can also make your fixed pattern work with

```
[^,]*,([0-9]*/[A-Z]*/[0-9]+)
```

Use it with `$1$`. If the string pattern is always `digits`+`,`+`digits`+`/`+`uppercase letters`+`/`+`digits`, you can just use

```
^\d+,(\d+/[A-Z]+/\d+)$
```

Again, with `$1$`.

Comment: Perhaps can also escape the **/** characters just in case with **\/**

Comment: I do not think so, jmeter does not use regex delimiters. [*Do not enclose the expression in / / - unless of course you want to match these characters as well.*](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

Comment: This time I have used [0-9]+/[A-Z]+/[0-9]+$ but value is not found again.Previously I was searching in the Body and  in Response message but it is not finding any value.Thank you stribizhev.

Comment: Probably, you should try with the `$1$` versions, or the version without the `$` anchor. I cannot help you more because I do not know what input string you get.

Comment: I have added images in my questions so please check where I am mistaking.

Comment: Not knowing what strings jmeter gets, I can just advise to use `[0-9]*/[A-Za-z]*/[0-9]+` with `$0$` template. Try with `Body` as `Field to check`, too.

Comment: I am using $1$ in template so will my variable VOUCHERNO will be changed to VOUCHERNO_g1 ?? please help.

Comment: See the reference: *If the match number is set to a non-negative number, and a match occurs, the variables are set as follows:
1) refName - the value of the template, 2) refName_gn, where n=0,1,2 - the groups for the match 3) refName_g - the number of groups in the Regex (excluding 0)*.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be enouth to solve your problem.

`^\d+,(\d+\/\w+\/\d+)`

For a better explanation:
https://regex101.com/r/oI0nP6/1

Comment: I am trying your expression ^\d+,(\d+\/\w+\/\d+) this time so what template I should choose and what will be the variable name then ? for "VOUCHERNO"

Comment: Yout should remove \ before / character, so the expression would be ^\d+,(\d+/\w+/\d+) ... try template: $1$, and i think variable name doesn't metter..